# Whats wrong with this XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my XML code -

```
<Para>
  <Desc>....</Desc>
  <References>
    <BookRef>
      <BookName>ABC of HTML</BookName>
      <Chapter>1</Chapter>
      <BookName>HTML : The Complete Reference</BookName>
      <Chapter>1</Chapter>
    </BookRef>
  </References>
</Para>
<Para>
  <Desc>....</Desc>
  <References>
    <BookRef>
      <BookName>ABC of XML</BookName>
      <Chapter>2</Chapter>
      <BookName>XML : The Complete Reference</BookName>
      <Chapter>10</Chapter><Chapter>11</Chapter>
    </BookRef>
  </References>
</Para>
```

I need to display the above in tabular format using `HTML Table Tag`. So that it should look like -

```
Description of Paragraph (the text between the Desc tags)

**Book Name**                                  **Chapters**
ABC of HTML                                      1
HTML: The Complete Reference                     1

Description of Paragraph (the text between the Desc tags)

**Book Name**                                  **Chapters**
ABC of XML                                       2
HTML: The Complete Reference                     10, 11
```

The reader can directly jump on the said chapters, I have created hyperlinks.
Below is the XSLT code -

```
<xsl:template match="References">
   <xsl:if test="CaseRef != ''"><br/>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="75%">Book Name</td>
        <td align="right">Chapters</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="BookName">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom">
          <xsl:for-each select="following::Chapter">
          <a id="lnk">
         <!-- This code will create a hyperlink to jump directly on the said chapter-->
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat('#',.),./@L)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </a>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I am missing something (might be much more) to get the required output!!

Comment: Your XSLT refers to a **CaseRef** element, but this is not present in the XML. Is this correct? Also, can you make sure your XML sample is 'well-formed' as it is lacking a single root element at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: It would also help if you explained what output you are currently getting and why it is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the CaseRef shud not be there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your XSLT. Firstly, within the **References** template you are looping over **BookName** name elements, but these are nested within **BookRef** elements, so you should be doing

```
<xsl:for-each select="BookRef/BookName" />
```

(Or preferably, use apply-templates to avoid too much nested code)

The next issue is with this loop, where you loop over the chapters

```
<xsl:for-each select="following::Chapter">
```

The problem here is that will pick up all following **Chapter** elements, even those that occur after a following **Bookname** element. One way to fix this is define a keep, to look-up only those **Chapter** elements for a given book.

```
<xsl:key 
   name="Chapters" 
   match="Chapter" 
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BookName[1])"/>
```

Then, assuming you are positioned on a **BookName** element, you can get the matching **Chapter** elements, like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('Chapters', generate-id())"/>
```

Try the following XSLT (Note I have removed the reference to **CaseRef** that occurred in your original XSLT)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="Chapters" match="Chapter" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BookName[1])"/>

   <xsl:template match="Desc">
      <p>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="References">
      <br/>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td width="75%">Book Name</td>
            <td align="right">Chapters</td>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="BookRef/BookName"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="BookName">
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </td>
         <td align="right" valign="bottom">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Chapters', generate-id())"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Chapter">
      <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <a id="lnk"><!-- This code will create a hyperlink to jump directly on the said chapter-->
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat('#',.),./@L)"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:text/>
      </a>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML (assuming it has a single root element), the following is output

```
<p>....</p>
<br/>
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="75%">Book Name</td>
      <td align="right">Chapters</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">ABC of HTML</td>
      <td align="right" valign="bottom">
         <a id="lnk" href="#1">1</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">HTML : The Complete Reference</td>
      <td align="right" valign="bottom">
         <a id="lnk" href="#1">1</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p>....</p>
<br/>
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="75%">Book Name</td>
      <td align="right">Chapters</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">ABC of XML</td>
      <td align="right" valign="bottom">
         <a id="lnk" href="#2">2</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">XML : The Complete Reference</td>
      <td align="right" valign="bottom">
         <a id="lnk" href="#10">10</a>,
         <a id="lnk" href="#11">11</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```